# Can I say "exercise to a better health"?

Tags: grammar, prepositions

Can I say "exercise to a better health" instead of "exercise for a better health"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

JavaLatte has brought up a very good point: health is uncountable, so the word "a" is wrong in both sentences.  The comparison of the corrected sentences:

> exercise to better health

means to exercise until better health is reached (not very commonly used.)

> exercise for better health

means to exercise because of a wish for better health.

They do amount to the same thing, but they are different ways of getting there.

Comment: Meh, they both end up arriving at the same meaning.  The difference is "for" indicates your motivation.  "to" indicates your destination.  Using health as a destination is a bit metaphorical.  But it's only odd because it's not idiomatic.  An advertizing campaign could change that.

Comment: @CandiedOrange: I've modified my answer slightly.  Does that please you?

Comment: Sure, have a point

Comment: @Zondo I think you answer is quite correct I just don't agree with part that says that is an odd thing to say because there is no definition of how much better counts as better I think a better health would be until you get to a point where you feel mentally & physically better or when you have lost the overweight which was making you obesse these are just two examples

Comment: @ManuelHernandez: I can see how you could say that.  I have edited.

Comment: @Zondo I see that thank you very much, please discard my previous comment as you have deleted the part mentioned in there

Comment: Health is uncountable, so you should not put **a** in front of it. See this NGram. https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=for+better+health%2Cfor+a+better+health&case_insensitive=on&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=18&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t4%3B%2Cfor%20better%20health%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bfor%20better%20health%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bfor%20Better%20Health%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cfor%20a%20better%20health%3B%2Cc0

Comment: @JavaLatte: Can't believe I missed that.  Edited.